# Look up my external ip while using proxy server still showing same ip adress like without proxy

Tags: windows-10, proxy, ip

Why does the [myexternalip.com](https://myexternalip.com/) website always display the same IP address, whether I use a proxy server or not? I have a Windows 10 operating system and change the proxy settings under  `Settings -> Proxy`. If I do not use a proxy server, then [myexternalip.com](https://myexternalip.com/) displays the IP address `82.207.XXX.XX`. If I use a proxy, e.g. `95.79.55.196:53281`, myexternalip.com still displays the IP address `82.207.XXX.XX`. Do I understand something wrong?

**Addition:**
I use Google Chrome browser. I did not change proxy settings in the browser but I did in the settings of my operating system (Win10). I'm just wondering why the proxy thing does not seem to work. Purely out of interest. I thought [myexternalip.com](https://myexternalip.com/) would at least show me the IP address of the proxy.
The answer from @MrLumute was very helpful, yet I wonder if there are not simple, public, free proxy that disguise the IP address. Even if I restart my browser, I get the same result. So it's not a caching problem

Comment: What browser do you use? Is it the same where you add the proxy? Please provide some more information. What kind of proxy you are using and what are you trying to achieve? Are you restarting the browser after you change the proxy? Maybe cache?

Comment: @IvanViktorovic I updated my answer. The point is, that I want to understand the proxy thing properly. And I think that's what I have when myexternalip.com displays the IP address of my proxy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all proxy servers work the same way. It’s important to understand exactly what functionality you’re getting from the proxy server, and ensure that the proxy server meets your use case.

> ### Transparent Proxy
>
> - A transparent proxy tells websites that it is a proxy server and it will still pass along your IP address, identifying you to the web server. Businesses, public libraries, and schools often use transparent proxies for content filtering: they’re easy to set up both client and server side.
>
> ### Anonymous Proxy
>
> - An anonymous proxy will identify itself as a proxy, but it won’t pass your IP address to the website – this helps prevent identity theft and keep your browsing habits private. They can also prevent a website from serving you targeted marketing content based on your location. For example, if CNN.com knows you live in Raleigh, NC, they will show you news stories they feel are relevant to Raleigh, NC. Browsing anonymously will prevent a website from using some ad targeting techniques, but is not a 100% guarantee.
>
> ### Distorting proxy
>
> - A distorting proxy server passes along a false IP address for you while identifying itself as a proxy. This serves similar purposes as the anonymous proxy, but by passing a false IP address, you can appear to be from a different location to get around content restrictions.
>
> ### High Anonymity proxy
>
> - High Anonymity proxy servers periodically change the IP address they present to the web server, making it very difficult to keep track of what traffic belongs to who. High anonymity proxies, like the TOR Network, is the most private and secure way to read the internet.

[Source](https://www.varonis.com/blog/what-is-a-proxy-server/)

Comment: I think that answers my question sufficiently. To try it out, I called the myexternalip.com site via proxysite.com and behold, it shows me a foreign IP address. Probably the one of the proxy server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no problem with the website you are using to confirm your new IP address? Try checking some other websites. I usually use https://whatismyip.live

If you still cannot see your proxy IP address then it means that the website you are using has no issue and the problem lies with your proxy settings. Have you tried using any proxy software or VPN service to see if things improve?